# Groovy Console with Java 9 throws JAXBException

Tags: java, groovy, java-9, groovy-console

Windows 10 OS, Java 9, Groovy 2.5.7 (newly upgraded)

I launch the Groovy Console, and run this

```
println "hello"
```

I get this exception

```
Exception thrown

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) about this, though not Groovy-specific, even less Groovy-Console-specific.

I tried the following lines as line 1:

```
@Grab( "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11" )
```

then

```
@Grab( "javax.xml.bind" )
```

... both of these gave

```
1 compilation error:

unexpected token: println at line: 3, column: 1
```

(i.e. the `println` line)

Comment: I can't help with groovy. Basically the needed class is not part of java anymore so you need to add it as a dependency.
If you just switched zo java 9 consider java 11 as 9 and 10 are not supported widely.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm aware of both your points.  Java 11 is meant to be "LTS" but I feel like I should  do a bit of time experimenting with Java 9 - in fact I don't really understand why there's been such a burst of activity with 9, 10, 11 and now 12 (seemingly with a suspicious change of licence).  Re adding dependencies: fine in the context of a Gradle project, but I don't know how to do this for the Groovy console.